# How to convert text file containing double quotes to csv format using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a text file(with header Actual_Output and saved it as actual.txt) containing data such as

```
Actual_Output
W
à
é
"
'
(
_
ç
²"
^
^
*
END
```

I want to convert it into csv file using powershell. I doing in this way

```
$DB = import-csv E:\actual.txt 
$outarray = @()

foreach ($Data in $DB)
{
$First = $Data.Actual_Output

$outarray += New-Object PsObject -property @{

    'Actual_Output' = $First

    }

write-host "Actual_Output: " $First 
write-Host ""
}
$outarray | export-csv 'E:\result.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
```

I am getting the output like this as shown in screenshot
[image]
I want each data to be listed in seperate cell. Actually double quote " is creating problem here. Please help in resolving this. Sorry if i am unclear in describing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested this, and it seems to work better:

```
Get-Content actual.txt | select -Skip 1 |
foreach {
 New-Object PSObject -Property @{Actual_Output = $_}
 } | export-csv result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

The file isn't well-formed as CSV initially, so Import-CSV isn't able to parse it correctly.